# Visibility of ViewBox set from code

Tags: c#, wpf, visibility, viewbox

On my Window, I have a ViewBox control, which contains a custom progress bar. I set its Visibility to Collapsed in design mode, because I need to display it in only certain moment (during login into app).

In my progress bar, which is usercontrol, I have event handler for VisibilityChanged event where I stop and start my animation.

When user clicks on the Login button, I need to show this ViewBox until Login is completed and collapse it again after success. But, when I (in code behind) set ViewBox.Visibility = Visible, it doesn't show up.

Can anybody tell me why, or how to fix it ?

XAML:

```
    <Viewbox x:Name="cpProgress" Width="50" Height="50" HorizontalAlignment="Center"   VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Grid.Row="1" Visibility="Collapsed" >
        <lc:CircularProgress />             
    </Viewbox>
```

Thanks

Comment: can you provide the whole xaml (with grid definition)?

Comment: Wpf will not start animations on elements that are not visible. So be sure to first set the visibility and than start animation. Can you set Visibility directly on CircularProgress?

Comment: Yes, I can set Visibility on `CircularProgress`, but that makes no difference. If I use Label instead of my usercontrol, I have same effect => Setting `Visibility = Visible`, but no label can be seen :/

Answer (score 1):

change `ViewBox.Visibility = Visible` to `cpProgress.Visibility = Visible` and ensure that the Grid has a proper row height defined for row 1.

Comment: The row where is the ViewBox has height of 155 (he ViewBox is a square 50x50), so I think the space here will not be a problem, or will ? 
    `cpProgress` is name of the viewbox. If I set Visibility on the ViewBox, it doesn't render, setting Visibility on my USerControl (`lc:CircularProgress`) has same effect i.e. no rendering.

Answer (score 0):

I've finally come to solution of this problem. It is really simple :). 
I've just forgot that If I run the login process in same thread, as my window is in, the UI will  hang until the login is completed. So solution is to spawn a new thread,run the login in its context and wait for `completed` flag to be set in UI's thread. The login process has to be running in asynchronous manner, so the UI could draw my usercontrol.